# why do i get this error while installing python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to install `Python 2.7` on `Windows 7 32-bit` version, but each time I install it I get this error

> An error occurred during the installation of assembly
>   'Microsoft.VC90.CRT, version="9.0.30729"

Comment: Just use python 3.6 instead

Comment: Is your installable python version as well for 32 bit?

Comment: i can't i must work with this version

Comment: try installing your MV VC libraries first

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/970652/error-1935-an-error-occurred-during-the-installation-of-assembly-micro

1. Install VC++ Redistributable 2008 for Visual Studio 2008
2. If an error still occurs : 
   Run the following tool to fix: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;946414